# Problem Reloadind a DIV containing javascript and java code

Tags: javascript, load

I have a DIV in my jsp page containing a javascript code + java code (see my code below). on click button I want to reload this DIV (using .load() function)  and all i get is a blank DIV.

is there an error on using this method or the fact that the div contains javascript and java code block the loading action.

NOTICE : the code work correctly when loading the hole page.
my code :

```
<div id="plan">
<div id='planningContent'>
<div class='gantt' id='GanttChartDIV'></div>
<script>
 var g = new 
JSGantt.GanttChart('g',document.getElementById('GanttChartDIV'), 'day');

        g.setShowRes(1); 
        g.setShowDur(1); 
        g.setShowComp(1); 
   g.setCaptionType('Resource');  
if( g ) {

    <%  
        try {
        con1 = ConnectionManager.getConnection();   
        String sql0="select * from liste_phases where 
      id_projet="+session.getAttribute("idProjet");
        Statement stm=con1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1=stm.executeQuery(sql0);
        while(rs1.next()){
                Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal1.setTime(rs1.getDate("dateDebut"));
                int year = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = (cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1;
                int day = cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                String datedeb= month+"/"+day+"/"+year;

                cal1.setTime(rs1.getDate("dateFin"));
                int year1 = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month1 = (cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1;
                int day1 = cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                String datefin= month1+"/"+day1+"/"+year1;
                    String sql5 = "select top 1 id from liste_actions 
   where id_projet="+session.getAttribute("idProjet")+" and 
  id_phase="+rs1.getInt("id");
                    Statement stmt5= con1.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs5=stmt5.executeQuery(sql5);
                    if(rs5.next()){
    %>
    g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(9999999,'<%=rs1.getString("intitule_Phase")%> (Macro Planning)','<%=datedeb%>','<%=datefin%>','d500c9','',0,'',0, 1, 0, 1));    
    g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(<%=rs1.getInt("id")%>,'<%=rs1.getString("intitule_Phase")%>','<%=datedeb%>','<%=datefin%>','dd0043','',0,'',0, 1, 0, 1));

    <%
                    }

    }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    %> 
    g.Draw();   
    g.DrawDependencies();
  }

  else

  {

    alert("not defined");

  }

</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>

///to reload the div i'm using this code 
$("#plan).load(" #planningContent");
```

Comment: 1) (Generally) Don't place scripts inside other elements, it does not give any benefit afaik other that potential problems. Under normal conditions, your scripts should be the last tags inside the body element and preferably external, not inline. 2) If you want to 'reload' the div, put the code inside a function that you can trigger again once you need to update the div.

Comment: Please show your button and JavaScript code you're using to "reload the DIV"

Comment: "Please show your button and JavaScript code you're using to "reload the DIV"" --> Done see the update

Comment: @Shilly : i did put the javascript code in on click event function the div is loaded but the modifications do not show up (the div is in the initial state)

Comment: actually the problem is that the data is loaded but "g.draw" not showing the new version or there is something conserving the old version of the gantt. have you an idea how the delete the "cookies" to show the new plan